# The default export is not a React Component in page: "/" NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Not sure why the error is coming up, heres my index.js and App.js (the default export). I have used export default in the app.js.

index.js:

```
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
<App />;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import NavBar from "../components/navBar";
import auth from "../services/authService";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    this.setState({ user });
  }

  render() {
    const { user } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <ToastContainer />
        <NavBar user={user} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: your index.js is wrong I guess. can you share the repository link or more details on how are you using index.js file?

Comment: That's all the index.js is being used for.

Comment: I've fixed it, just needed to put the content of index into a class and export it.

Comment: For some reason Next doesn't allow wrapping the content in a fragment. If you remove that/replace it with a div it should work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed, made index.js a class and exported it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
class Index extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return <App />;
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 38):

Date: 23/01/2021

I've also faced this issue on my `Next.js` app.

If you're using a functional component instead of a class component you'll get this error as well in some casses. Exactly I don't know why this is happening but I just resolved this issue by `exporting` my component at the bottom of the page.

Like this,

Case Error scenario:

```
export default function Home(){
      return (<>some stuffs</>)
}

Home.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    return {}
}
```

```
Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/"
```

How to resolved it?

I just put my export at the bottom my page and then it'll be gone.

Like this,

```
function Home(){
      return (<>some stuffs</>)
}

Home.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
    return {}
}

export default Home;
```

Hopefully, it'll be helpful for you!

Answer (score 24):

In next.js all pages has to be exported default. Either this way

```
export default function RegisterPage() {
  return (
    <>
     
    </>
  );
}
```

or

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <BaseLayout>
    
    </BaseLayout>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

If not you get that error.

Answer (score 11):

I was getting this error because of a completely different reason, In my case for some reason I removed the code In my `app/layout.tsx` file and had forgotten about it, but this is what was causing the error: `error - Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/my_page"`.

To fix it I just put the following code in my  `app/layout.tsx` file:

```
import './globals.css'

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

This is probably a rare occurrence but hopefully it helps.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was helpful to me, because you drew my attention to the layout.tsx file. I created it, but forgot to write any code to it, so it was empty, hence at compilation, I was getting the error.

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this issue but in my case i was using the route group in next.js 13+. Check your `layout.tsx / layout.jsx` as well. Make sure both `<your-component>.tsx` and `layout.tsx` have default imports. E.g `export default <your-component>` in both files

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen if you are throwing an error without catching it before the initial page renders during server-side-rendering. Take for instance the following:

```
const Component = (props) => {
  return (
    <div {...props}>
       hello!
    </div>
  );
};

Component.getInitialProps = async ({ query, req, asPath }) => {
  throw new Error('Application is crashing without catch');
}
```

Make sure you are catching unexpected errors prior to the page being rendered.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problem with Next.js 13.4:

```js
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I solved them by just importing React:

```
import React from "react"

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>Home</div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 2):

Check all your folders and look for the layout file that is empty and delete it or fill it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

NextJS 14 - I did get same error message when created a layout.tsx file but left it empty (forget about it) and then on my child components I get error "default export is not a React Component in page..." which was a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this just happened because I had a .ts and not a .tsx file. It might do the same thing with .js instead of .jsx extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error: **The default export is not a React Component in page: "/_app"**.

Next 12.2.5

In my case I was transitioning from a React app to Nextjs.

My index.js file was a functional component, but I was missing the following on my _app.js

```
import './App.css'

/* I was missing the following code */
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Delete node_modules and yarn.lock/package-lock.json
2. run yarn install or npm install

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue because I was using a fragment <></> around the html. After removing it, it worked as aspected.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 I also go this error. I created a new folder about and created 2 files one is page.tsx and other one is layout.tsx and I wrote some code in page.tsx and I run it I got similar error. I simply deleted the layout.tsx then it worked :).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35494681)

Answer (score 0):

"Just realised that when using route grouping, this error occurs when you have an `empty layout file` within your route group. To resolve it, write code for layout file or delete it for the time being." [Answer by](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/31872#discussioncomment-6803178)

Answer (score 0):

Faced this same issue in Nextjs, and the following worked for me.

Instead of using const in layout use function, this seems to be working.

```
export default function LayoutName ({ children })  {
return (
    <div>
        {children}
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue in my next js app. The problem i was facing was because of the missing semi-colon at the end of export default page.

Previous code:

```
export default page
```

Fixed code:

```
export default page;
```