# Is it possible to use only named exports in a NextJS project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

WARNING: It's not a duplicate to: [The default export is not a React Component in page: "/" NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873698)
I'm looking for a solution with named exports! I know I can switch to exports default.

I'm writing a NextJS App and would like to only use named exports. When I write my components in the router with named exports:

`_app.ts`:

```js
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

export const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

I'll get the following error:

```
Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: "/_app"
```

I can not find any documentation on the router of nextjs where it says that you have to use exports default. Or what kind of syntax is using it.

Comment: I hate to be one of those people who question your purpose, but... _why??_ NextJS doesn't have this by default because the devs didn't see a need for it. Look into your implementation: are you sure you absolutely cannot use default exports? (I can't think of a situation.)

Comment: Sure... it's true that [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages) don't explicitly say this... but let me ask you something. How else would the framework know what to import? I mean, if you export some page called `MySuperCoolPage`, how does Next.js know to import that specifically? Default exports don't have this problem, since they don't have a name.

Comment: In our coding guidelines we decided to use named exports since we think they have a few advantages compared to default exports. (Explicit over implicit, better UX while developing, easier refactoring....) Now we are just looking for an option to do ALL exports the same to follow consistency. We know that we could split the router components and the UI components. :D

Comment: @caTS That's a good reason. It's seems we have to combine the two exports :)

Comment: @caTS It could import the entire namespace, then examine its members. If no suitable default export is found, the named exports could be looked through. If one named export looks like a React component, it could then be used. (If two or more named exports look like React components, an error could be thrown due to ambiguity.) That's not how things are now, but it'd be theoretically pretty easy to set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked into this to the best of my ability and the only solution I could come up with for you is to **use default exports for pages that will be used in routing, and named exports for everything else**.

This should hopefully suffice because it is unlikely you will ever import a page as Next.js should be handling that import automatically under the hood with its router.